# Bernoulli distribution in Python/Scipy

Tags: python, scipy, bernoulli-probability

I'm trying to use the Bernoulli distribution to generate a matrix in which each line cell has a probability of `line_id/total_lines` to be `1.0`.

That's my code:

```
from scipy.stats import bernoulli
import numpy

img_size = 100
img_number = 100

res = numpy.zeros((img_number+1, 6))

image_files = []
for i in range(1):
    image_base = Dt.Data(xd=img_size, yd=img_size)
    for p in numpy.arange(0.0, 1.0, 1.0/img_size):
        s = bernoulli.rvs(p, size=img_size)
        image_base.data[int(p * img_size), ...] = s
        if not s.any() == True:
            print int(p * img_size), s
    if i == 0:
        Dv.DataVisualization.plot_data(image_base, 'bin'+str(i))
    image_files.append(image_base)

from PIL import Image

def plot_data(data, file_path):
    output = Image.fromarray(numpy.uint8(data.data * 255))
    output.save(file_path + '.png', 'PNG')
```

However, for each image generated I'm getting a line (that's not the first one), fulfilled by zeros. That's a least odd:

[image]
[image]
[image]

This:

```
if not s.any() == True:
    print int(p * img_size), s
```

printed just the first line. However, I still can see three lines (always the same lines) fulfilled by 0 over all images.

Comment: I think you are getting two such lines.

Comment: Yes, the first one (which is correct) and another one, which may be correct, but is strange that this happens at the same line over all images.

Comment: If you include the first line, there are three.  The second is about 1/4 of the way from the top, and the third is about 1/2 of the way from the top.

Comment: Try it with a far smaller image size, e.g. 3 x 3, or 4 x 4

Comment: The result seems fine for smaller images. However, s.all() == 0 still seems to result in s.any() == 0.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may be misusing Numpy's `all()` and `any()`.  The expression `s.any()` evaluates to a boolean.

If I want to determine whether I have a Numpy array whose elements are all zero, I should check the condition `not s.any() == True`.